# XML output from ksoap response

Tags: android, xml, xml-deserialization, ksoap

SoapObject result=(SoapObject)soapEnvelope.getResponse();

with aht.responsedump i get it

so Phonebook is my root element from my xml which looks like

22245278
    
    
    0
  
  
    22245648
    
    
    0

how to acces the child of the root and get my data

Answer (score 0):

Update your question to be readable maybe.

In any case, just parse the SoapObject with getProperty and getAttribute